# Is it possible to return all the grouped values ​of a field for an elasticsearch search?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following query that most often returns in the field `['hits'] ['total']` more hits than what I specify without `size`.

As in the example:

```
query_body = {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 40,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match":{
                        "query": 'caderno preto',
                        "fields":[
                            "DescricaoSEO",
                            "TermoBusca",
                            "Fabricante"
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match":"100%",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My query returns the first 40 hits, but when I print the total hits I have:

```
print(retornoES['hits']['total'])
{'value': 426, 'relation': 'eq'}
```

Is there any way to return one of the fields with all 426 in the query keeping the size of the first 40?

This is my mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "Ativo": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "BlackFriday": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "CD_Classificacao": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "CD_Grupo": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "CD_Subgrupo": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "CD_TipoProduto": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "CampoPesquisa": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "Codigo": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "CurvaABC": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "DS_Classificacao": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "DS_Grupo": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "DS_Parcelamento": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "DePor": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "Descontinuado": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "Descricao": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "DescricaoSEO": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "Download": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "Estoque": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "ExclusivoParceiro": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "Fabricante": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "Garantia": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "Imagem": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "Link": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "LinkProduto": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "NM_Produto": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "Parcelamento": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "PrecoCusto": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "PrecoDesconto": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "PrecoOriginal": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "PrecoVenda": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "PrecoVendaAssinatura": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "Prioridade": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "Selo": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "TemEstoque": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "TermoBusca": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "VL_PrecoVenda": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking... do you want all the 426 hits to return in the response while specifying size=40?

Comment: @Val,  Return my 40 hits and another json-like node with all 426 of a specific field. as if it were a new list inside an object

Comment: That's definitely possible. Which field exactly?

Comment: @MarcoSouza, now I got it, you can use the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html for that

Comment: @Val, Codigo,  edited with mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to return only 40 hits but all 426 occurrences of a given field (e.g. `Codigo`), you can do it this way:

```
query_body = {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 40,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match":{
                        "query": 'caderno preto',
                        "fields":[
                            "DescricaoSEO",
                            "TermoBusca",
                            "Fabricante"
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match":"100%",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "occurrences": {
            "top_hits": {
                "_source": ["Codigo"],
                "size": 1000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll get only 40 hits, but 426 occurrences of `Codigo` in `aggregations.occurrences.hits`.

You might need to change the settings of your index in order to make this work, because by default only 100 hits will return from a `top_hits` aggregation:

```
PUT my-index/_settings
{
   "index.max_inner_result_window": 1000
}
```

If `Codigo` is unique across all documents, then the above query will work for your need, however, if `Codigo` is not unique, you might be better off using a `terms` aggregation (as suggested by ES Ninja)

```
query_body = {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 40,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match":{
                        "query": 'caderno preto',
                        "fields":[
                            "DescricaoSEO",
                            "TermoBusca",
                            "Fabricante"
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match":"100%",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "occurrences": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "Codigo.keyword",
                "size": 1000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a particular field for all your matching docs(426 in your example), while keeping the size as 40, if this is the case, then its not possible.

`total` means the total number of documents in your index, matching the query while `size` is used to return the top `based on size` documents(based on the score) in your index.

You can use the [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-source-filtering.html) or [retrieved particular field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html) in the search response, but you have to give a high value of size param(default is 10 for performance reasons).